# Rails active admin review user posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to allow the admin to review the description. So, whenever user posts the description admin can either approve or reject it. If approved it'll display on the index page. At the moment the user can add the description but it can't be reviewed by admin. Is there any way I could do this?

index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p> <%= post.description %> </p>
<% end %>
```

admin/post.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :description

  index do
    id_column
    column :description
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new boolean field to post called reviewed with default value false:

```
class AddReviewedToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :reviewed, :boolean, default: false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :reviewed
  end
end
```

then create on AA under index page a button the set it as reviewed:

```
index do
  id_column
  column :description
  column "" do |post|
    link_to 'Mark as reviewed', admin_posts_reviewed_path(post)
  end
end
```

then the last thing create a reviewed action on `admin/posts.rb`:

```
def reviewed
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.present?
    @post.update_attribute(:reviewed, true)
    flash[:notice] = 'Post marked as reviewed'        
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Could not find post'
  end

  redirect_to admin_posts_path
end
```

don't forget to add the action to routes.rb!

now you can display it if the boolean field is true.

code is not tested this is from my head.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my routes i got `match '/admin_posts_review', to: 'posts#admin_posts_review', via: 'post'`. However I get `No route matches [GET] "/admin_post_review"` error. Any idea why?

Comment: Consider using a `batch_action` for the "mark as reviewed" action.